# How to remove "_" from a string that us dynamically sent from an external source

Tags: string, lua

I am trying to right a code that when a value is sent from FIX tag 1 example 1=AB_123 to remove the _ then process the new tag as AB123

The below is something more static, however I want it to be more Dynamic and have it always remove the "_" found in account 1

```
Acct = GetValue(1)

if string.find(Acct, "AB_123")  then
newAcct = AB123 
return newAcct
else
return PASS
end
```

Comment: `Acct=Acct:gsub("_","")`

Answer (score 0):

Since Acct is exactly `AB_123` you can change string.find to direct comparison using `==`.

To remove `_` you can simply create new string and return it.

```lua
if Acct == "AB_123" then
    return "AB123"
else
    return PASS -- I suppose PASS is a variable, if you want it to be a string use "PASS"
end
```

Comment: This isn't a great answer. Whilst it does solve the very particular case the question technically asked for, it's a very specific solution. Teaching the generic solution would've been better, even if you left the specific case as well.

Comment: @ATaco It wasn't specified though

Comment: The question does quite clearly ask how to remove an underscore from dynamic input. Either way, I'm just offering ways to improve the answer.

Comment: @ATaco Missed that, well, Personage basically gave the answer he needs

Answer (score 0):

To remove all occurrences of a given pattern from a string, use the `string.gsub` function. You can read about it [here](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html). Note that this will replace *every* underscore in your tag with an empty string.

```
-- Requires: tag_in is a string.
-- Effects : returns tag_in with underscores ('_') removed.
local function get_tag(tag_in)
    -- Call gsub as a member function of the string class.
    local tag = tag_in:gsub("_", "")
    return tag
end
```

`string.gsub` returns two values: a string with replacements made, and the number of times that the given pattern occurred in the input string. In the above function, since—I am assuming—the second return value is irrelevant, only the first is captured in a local variable and returned.